# What is the suggested version of oprofile on Linux kernel 3.4?

Tags: linux-kernel

I want to use the oprofile tool on Linux kernel version 3.4. If I understand correctly, the latest oprofile version is 1.1.0. Is this correct?

In one of the articles I saw, 0.9x versions of oprofile is used on 3.x versions of the Linux kernel. Please suggest which version of oprofile has to be used for Linux kernel version 3.4.